# Configure TigerVNC Server to start with system in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, gnome, systemd, vnc

I am trying to configure TigerVNC Server to run on [Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME). I installed the latest version ([1.8](https://bintray.com/tigervnc/stable/download_file?file_path=ubuntu-16.04LTS%2Famd64%2Ftigervncserver_1.8.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb)) of [TigerVNC](http://tigervnc.org/) using [this post](http://www.stoutpanda.com/2016/10/20/tigervnc-ubuntu-1604-xenial-xerus/). If I start a server using:

```
vncserver :4 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24 -nolisten tcp -localhost
```

it works perfectly. I can connect to *display 4* over SSH, and have full access to my computer, without unlocking the real (physical) displays in my lab. Also, I can tune the geometry to match my laptop's display, so everything is perfect.

Then I tried to get the server to start at startup, using `systemd`, and I found [this post](https://alchemist.digital/articles/set-up-vnc-server-multiple-distros/#ubuntu) to help me. However, I am running the GNOME desktop, and the settings from the blog are for Unity. I do not have Unity installed on my machine, and I would prefer to avoid it.

How do I modify steps 7 and 8 in that post to use GNOME desktop instead of Unity? I know that it does not work if they are skipped, as I just get a black screen when I connect remotely.

---

In fact, if there is another way to ensure `vncserver` is started at startup, that will be accepted as answer as well. TigerVNC does install a script called `vncserver` in `/etc/init.d/`, but I am not able to launch it using `update-rc.d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `systemd` Unit file worked for me:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start TigerVNC Server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=user
PAMName=login
PIDFile=/home/user/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver :%i -depth 24 -geometry 1920x1080 -nolisten tcp -localhost
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Be sure to replace `user` with your actual username on lines corresponding to `User` and `PIDFile` under `[Service]`.

- I saved this file as `vncserver@.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/`
- Enabled it with `systemctl enable vncserver@4.service` which creates a symlink file `vncserver@4.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` pointing to `vncserver@.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/`
- Started the service with `systemctl start vncserver@4`

To adapt it to your needs, please use your preferred *display* number instead of *4* (as I did) when enabling. Also, ensure that you have initialized the vncserver outside of this service Unit file before starting the service. This would ensure the password, and the necessary files (`xstartup`, etc.) are created. The easiest way to do that would be to run the command against `ExecStart` under `[Service]` in the Unit file. For my case, that translates to:

```
vncserver :4 -depth 24 -geometry 1920x1080 -nolisten tcp -localhost
```

---

Source: I adapted the Unit file from [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: Please refer to [this question, comments and answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1013329/468662) for multiple user support.